# Fundamental group of a compact manifold

Tags: group-theory, manifolds

In an article I am currently reading, the author tells us that for compact (finite dimensional topological) manifolds X and finite groups $\Gamma$, the set $$\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X,\Gamma)/\Gamma$$ where $\Gamma$ acts on the set $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X,\Gamma)$ via $(\varphi\cdot\gamma)([c]):=\gamma^{-1}\varphi([c])\gamma$, is **finite**.

This quotient space is naturally in bijection with the isomorphism classes of principal bundles over $X$ with structure group $\Gamma$.

> How do you show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X,\Gamma)/\Gamma$ is finite?

I can see one pathway which would be to show that the fundamental group of $X$ is finitely generated, which would entail that the set $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X,\Gamma)$ itself is finite. I thought I remembered a proof of this fact from John M. Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, and I tried in vain to reproduce it. He actually shows that the fundamental group is countable.

I have two "proofs" or rather "plausible arguments" that work in the differentiable setting. The first uses Morse theory : $X$ is homotopy equivalent/homeomorphic (which one is it?) to a *finite* CW-complex, and those have finitely generated fundamental groups.

The other one uses a riemannian metric on $X$ and a (finite) cover $\mathcal{O}_1,\dots,\mathcal{O}_N$ by geodesically convex open sets. I recall reading in Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* (where it is cited without proof but with a reference) that those exist. It seems plausible that such open sets $\mathcal{O}$ should be contractible : you can take some fixed point $x\in\mathcal{O}$ and define $$C:\mathcal{O}\times[0,1]\to\mathcal{O},~(y,t)\mapsto c_{x,y}(1-t)$$ where $c_{x,y}:[0,1]\to\mathcal{O}$ is the (unique) shortest geodesic that joins $x\rightarrow y$. By definition of being geodesically convex, there is indeed a unique shortest geodesic between any two points in $\mathcal{O}$ and it stays inside $\mathcal{O}$ at all times, and so $C$ is well defined (and smooth).

The next step copies a proof of Van Kampens's theorem : fix a basepoint $x_0\in X$. For any $i,j$, $\mathcal{O}_i\cap\mathcal{O}_j$ is either empty or non empty and geodesically convex. Pick points $x_{ij}\in\mathcal{O}_i\cap\mathcal{O}_j$ and paths $c_{ij}$ that link $x_o\rightarrow x_{ij}$. Also, for any $i,j,j'$ with $\mathcal{O}_i\cap\mathcal{O}_j\neq\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{O}_i\cap\mathcal{O}_{j'}\neq\emptyset$ define a path $$c_{j,i,j'}:x_0\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{c_{ij}} x_{i,j}\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{*} x_{ij'}\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{\overline{c_{ij'}}} x_0$$ where $*$ is any path inside $\mathcal{O}_i$ that links $x_{ij}\rightarrow x_{ij'}$ and $\overline{c_{ij'}}$ is $c_{ij'}$ in reverse. The $c_{j,i,j'}$ should span $\pi_1X$, thus showing that it is finitely generated (contractability of $\mathcal{O}_i\cap\mathcal{O}_j$ is key).

My worry with both proofs is that I don't really know Morse theory, and I don't know why geodesically convex open sets exist around every point in a riemannian manifold. Of course, this could be remedied by studying the subjects, but I wonder :

> Are there more elementary proofs of the fact that compact (possibly smooth) manifolds have finitely generated fundamental group?

Also,

> is it true that compact *topological* manifolds have finitely generated fundamental groups?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes, where Ryan Budney gives a reference that every compact manifold has the homotopy-type of a finite CW complex.

Comment: The answers to both questions is *yes*: there are some supplementary exercises in Munkres's *Topology* on the fundamental group, which contains an outline of the proof in exercise format.

Comment: @SteveD I'll have a look!